# Why does this list always grab the first item?

Tags: list, lua

This function is supposed to go through *all* of the list items and check whether the argument coordinates are close to the position in the list items (the second and third numbers in the nested lists), but from the readout I can tell that it only ever checks the first one.

```
function CapitalProximity(x,y)
  local positions = {{"lusitani",31,328},{"ebdani",78,592},{"carpetani",101,329}}
  for i = 1, #positions do
    local dist = distance_2D(x,y,positions[i][2],positions[i][3])
    print("position is "..dist.." from "..positions[i][1])
    if dist < 20 then
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `return` terminates the whole function.  Do not use `return` inside a loop unless you really want to exit the function.

Comment: I do want to exit the function when a solution is found. The question was whether I'm accessing the list items right in the fourth line, as I only get the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both branches of the `if` return from inside the loop, the loop can never reach a second iteration. To get results based on all elements from the `positions` array, you need to make a table to store them:

```
function CapitalProximity(x,y)
  local positions = {{"lusitani",31,328},{"ebdani",78,592},{"carpetani",101,329}}
  local result = {} -- This will hold all results.
  for i = 1, #positions do
    local dist = distance_2D(x,y,positions[i][2],positions[i][3])
    print("position is "..dist.." from "..positions[i][1])
    result[i] = dist < 20 -- Store the current result.
  end
  return result
end
```

Comment: Ah! So it wasn't the way I accessed the lists, it was a logical error. Thank you very much, luther!